# How to prove this property of convex conjugate?

Tags: real-analysis

I tend to prove that $(th)^*(x) = th^*(x/t)$.

However this is what I get,

\begin{align*}
h^*(x/t) = \sup_{y\in\text{dom}(h)}(x/t)^Ty - h(y)\\
th^*(x/t) = \sup_{y\in\text{dom}(h)}x^Ty - th(y)\\
(th)^*(x)=\sup_{y'\in\text{dom}(th)}x^Ty' - h(y')\\
\text{Because,}\\
y \in \text{dom}(h) \Rightarrow y'=ty \in \text{dom}(th)\\
(th)^*(x)=\sup_{y\in\text{dom}(h)}x^Tty - th(y)\\
\end{align*}

Comment: @littleO Sorry for the confusion, the first two line are separated from the rest, so for the derivation of $(th)*$, it starts from the third line, however I am not sure whether my last line is valid or not.

Comment: Oops my question didn't make sense so I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third line, shouldn't $h(y')$ really be $t h(y')$?  And then you are done.

Edit: So, in more detail, the third line should say:
\begin{align}
(th)^*(x) = \sup_{y'\in \text{dom}(th)} x^T y' - th(y').
\end{align}
Because $h$ and $th$ have the same domain, this expression for $(th)^*(x)$ is identical to the expression you derived for $t h^*(x/t)$.  So your proof is then complete.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. Can I say $th^*(x/t) = \sup_{y\in\text{dom}(h)}x^Ty - th(y) \text{ and } 
(th)^*(x)=\sup_{y'\in\text{dom}(th)}x^Ty' - th(y')$? They have different domain for $y$.